# How do I disable Markdown code block generation?

Tags: html, markdown

I have an unusual situation.  I am in a transitional state for a website that will eventually be a wiki-like site that uses markdown files to generate documentation.  However, for our phase 0 demonstration to upper management, I need to use HTML instead of markdown for advanced layouts.  This leads to large portions of the Markdown files being HTML.  Generally speaking, this is working fine, but sometimes the "4 spaces means code block" "feature" of markdown means that instead of rendering the page, I just get the HTML pasted to the screen in a <pre>.

So, my question is, how can I turn off the "4 spaces means code block" thing?  IMO, this is an idiotic design in the first place, but it's really screwing with my current project!

For example:

I have a banner

```
<div class="banner detail">
    <div class="banner-inner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

On some pages, this renders exactly as expected.  On others, it spits out the "banner-inner" div and everything inside it to the page.  Hell, even convincing this editor to display that code snippet instead of processing it took 5 minutes of trial and error poking...

Please, some one help me turn off or get around (without simply not using indenting...) this "feature"!!

Comment: What's the wiki software you're using / what's doing the Markdown processing in the first place on your site?

Comment: Looks like something called "PegDownProcessor" judging by the Java package include.  Looking up the main github for it, appropriately shows that it's deprecated.  Oi.

Comment: Generally Markdown comes as a whole package as the rules don't anticipate any customization. However, there are some implementations which allow customization. You'll need to check the documentation for the implementation you are using to see if it supports any sort of customization.

Comment: Oh and indentation for code blocks was absolutely brilliant ~20 years ago when Markdown was created. Sure, today most people prefer fenced code blocks, but that is a significantly newer unofficial third party add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, whether this "feature" can be turned off is relegated to a customization question for the specific software package in use.

On the bright side, I was able to eventually determine that the specific problem I was having was caused by the engine interpreting invalid HTML code (ie, missing a closing tag) as code to be displayed rather than processed.  So in the end, seeing this happen actually tended to mean that I had a bug to fix.